# IIS can't serve files with accents and spaces in filenames

Tags: windows, iis, filesystems

My server recently stopped serving files with accents and spaces in the filename.

An example:

```
http://jf-monteabraao.pt/UserFiles/File/OP%C3%87%C3%95ES%20DO%20PLANO%20-%20OR%C3%87AMENTO%202010.pdf
```

I didn't install anything except [UrlScan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc242650.aspx), but I can't find anything related to the problem in `urlscan.ini`.

Answer (score 4):

Solved. The problem was in the `urlscan.ini` file. Property

```
AllowHighBitCharacters=0
```

must be set to `1` value.